# Multiple insert statements - increment variable

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table

```
number | letter
-------+---------
1      | A
2      | B
```

And I have this code:

```
declare @counter as int = 0

while (@counter < 16)
begin
    set @counter = @counter + 1

    insert into table (number, letter) 
    values (@counter, 'A')

    insert into table (number, letter) 
    values (@counter, 'B')
end
```

The problem with I have with this statement is that it is producing something like this:

```
number | letter
-------+----------
1      | A
1      | B
2      | A
2      | B
```

What I wanted is there are 8 rows since the counter stops after 15 and @counter started from 0

```
number | letter
-------+---------
1      | A
2      | B
3      | A
4      | B
5      | A
6      | B
7      | A
8      | B
```

I have tried putting `BEGIN` and `END` per statement but I still can't achieve my goal:

```
declare @counter as int = 0

while (@counter < 16)
begin
    insert into table (number, letter) 
    values (@counter, 'A')
end
begin
    insert into table (number, letter) 
    values (@counter, 'B')

    set @counter = @counter + 1
end
```

Comment: Why not just use an `IDENTITY` or `SEQUENCE`?

Comment: Generally speaking, effective and efficient SQL will avoid loops at all costs. A set-based approach is preferred. I also suspect that you place importance on the sequential ID values and the pattern of values in the letter column - something that will likely flow into any code using this "table" via assumption. Beware!

Comment: thank you for your inputs. this is not intended for production purposes and i am justcreating a script that will simplify my process of inserting test data in test database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm with @Larnu, why not simply using `IDENTITY` on `number`?

But if you insist doing it on your own, one method would be to increment the counter by `2` instead of `1` and insert the current value along with `'A'` and the current value `+ 1` along with `'B'`.

```
DECLARE @counter AS integer = 1;

WHILE @counter <= 8
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO elbat
              (number,
               letter)
              VALUES (@counter,
                      'A');
  INSERT INTO elbat
              (number,
               letter)
              VALUES (@counter + 1,
                      'B');
  SET @counter = @counter + 2;
END;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=bc2980e194f6b480460343fe228f3482)

Comment: Not sure why this needs a `WHILE` at all...

Answer (score 0):

You can just use two cross-joined virtual `VALUES` clauses for this. **No `WHILE` loops needed.**

```sql
INSERT INTO [table] (number, letter)
SELECT
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)),
  v2.letter
FROM (VALUES
    (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)
) v1(counter)
CROSS JOIN (VALUES ('A'), ('B') ) v2(letter);
```

[dbfiddle.uk](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=5bad762b9453fb4d1fe24ac4e6307f0e)

For a variable amount of rows, you can still use this, by cross-joining multiple times and using `TOP`.

This is similar to [Itzik Ben-Gan's numbers function](https://sqlperformance.com/2021/01/t-sql-queries/number-series-solutions-1)

```sql
DECLARE @I int = 16;

WITH L0 AS (
    SELECT n = 1
    FROM (VALUES
        (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)
    ) v(n)
),
L1 AS (
    SELECT TOP (@i)
        n = 1
    FROM L0 a, L0 b, L0 c, L0 d  -- add more cross-joins for more than 65536
)
SELECT
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)),
  v2.letter
FROM L1
CROSS JOIN (VALUES ('A'), ('B') ) v2(letter);
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=94efacd260178597beddb3aaa1f4fb62)

Comment: the problem with this statement is that the times you need to key in the '(1)' depending on the number of rows that you want the statement insert/return. like in this example, if you need 32 rows, you need to include the '(1)' 16 times thereby suffering the quality of readability and the amount of time to create the statement whereas when using the while loop, you just need to declare the number of times the counter will stop like in sticky bit's answer.

Comment: No, 16 is my standard size for a numbers table anyway, so it was just convenient. When you need a variable number of rows, you can use multiple cross joins and `TOP`, have edited

Comment: I saw the fiddle and it works well. Though when I tried to add a column in the final select clause and added a cross join value, it doesn't work as what I expected.

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=eb8b690b7b8809b27635d89688a3ffc2

Comment: What was your expected result? That looks similar to your original?

Comment: ABAB on the first column, CDCD on the second column

Comment: Why would it do that? It needs to get every combination (a cartesian product), so you need A with C, A with D, B with C, B with D. There is no reason for it to emit the same pair twice. If you mean the ordering of the numbers, you can change `ORDER BY (SELECT 1)` to `ORDER BY v2.letter, v3.letter2`

Comment: I tried changing with order by but is still showing AABB on 1st then CDCD on 2nd. What I mean is it should be ABAB then CDCD https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=3ead7a3e2e0195c219083a4f7582f9ab

Comment: Again: if you pair those up as you are asking, you end up with `1AC` `2AD` `3AC` `4AD` so you have duplicates but not every combination. This gives you every combination. Unless I'm not understanding something: please state how you would like your rows to be returned, tell me *each row separately*. Or how about you show me your expected results in a fiddle, like this https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b6c77bd91102e4a1019fbabc567dced4

Comment: the second query in your fiddle link is the result set that I am looking for (1AC, 2BD, 3AC, 4BD)

Comment: Well that makes absolutely no sense, because you are just repeating pairs. You could do it if you *really* wanted like this `CROSS JOIN (VALUES ('A','C'), ('B','D'), ('A','C'), ('B','D') ) v2(letter, letter2)` https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=bb4bde583e849ea76dd48ec427760baf

Comment: thanks. but in terms of amount of time it will take in writing the query, I would still go with sticky bit's answer. much easier to read and write for additional columns.